# Is it possible to rollback an ArcGIS Pro Update instead of uninstalling/reinstalling?

Tags: installation, arcgis-pro

I had a moment of weakness today agreed to update my ArcGIS Professional with the latest version: `1.0.0.1808`.  But unfortunately, it is crashing so bad that its unusable and I need to rollback.  Is this possible or is my only option to uninstall completely and reinstall from an earlier version?

If I have to reinstall, can I install and then update to a specific version but not the latest version?  I have the `1.0.0.1472` installer.

Is there a list of ArcGIS Pro releases versions and when they were released?

Comment: Have you submitted any of this crash information to the Pro beta forums or tech support? I thought 1808 was the released (1.0) version of Pro, but I might be wrong. There has to my knowledge only been 1 updated pushed out (or 2?) and didn't hear anything about it causing crashes. My point is: any info you got regarding this would be good for us (esri) to get

Comment: I submitted a couple crash reports which included a screen grab of the thread that was maxing out the CPU just before the crash: http://i.imgur.com/SjegPfO.png

Comment: And I ended up uninstalling, reinstalling,so I'm all set.  If there are only 2 releases, then I was probably mixing up the beta releases.

Comment: Thanks for submitting the reports, we do review those. Glad you're up and running. Best I can tell 1808 is final, 1472 would be a beta version. There has been 2 X.0.X updates since final, thus 1.0.2 is current. Dont have an answer about uninstalling those updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, there are 3 releases of ArcGIS Pro:

- 1.0.0 (1808)
- 1.0.1 (patch)
- 1.0.2 (patch)

1.1 (full release) will be available shortly. The [help landing page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/) will always mention the newest (current) version. The closest item to a list of versions released, and when they were released can be found [here on the support-patches website](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/list/productid/220).

For the 1.0.x versions of ArcGIS Pro, **no**, you cannot roll back from one version to another. You'd have to uninstall and download the old one. In 1.1 and onward, this may change (ability to remove patch), but since 1.1 and any potential patches haven't been released, I can't confirm this will happen.

As for choosing a specific version/patch:

- I don't have access to the download site, so I cannot confirm what you get/see on there.
- Using the "updates" option built into Pro will always update to the most recent patch available. You cannot select a specific patch/version.